How to avoid repetition of fields when logging with tracing
I want to avoid repeating fields when logging, like this:
let original_url = "https://google.com";
let request_id = 123;

info!("making request", original_url, request_id);

// Make request, get some response.

warn!("request failed", original_url, request_id, status_code = response.status_code(), success = false);

I have to repeat the same fields multiple times.
Here is how I imagine it should work:
let myspan = span!(
   tracing::Level::INFO,
   "http_request",
   original_url,
   request_id,
);

info!("making request");

// Make request, get some response.

myspan.record("status_code", response.status_code());

myspan.log(tracing::Level::WARN, "request failed", success = false);

The output would then look like this:
{
  "timestamp": "2024-04-17T10:35:17.354371Z",
  "level": "WARN",
  "message": "request failed",
  "success": false,
  "status_code": 500,
  "original_url": "http://google.com",
  "request_id": 123
}

So you can dynamically record more fields, log using the span data, etc.
Unfortunately this doesn't work or is hard for a variety of reasons:

The fields from the span don't appear unless you configure your subscriber with with_current_span(true).
If you do, the fields from the span are nested in a span fields See https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/pull/2705 for someone's attempt to address this.
Furthermore, if you use with_current_span, it applies to all logging. I only want it to apply for logging with this span, since other logging has noisy spans.
You can't actually dynamically add fields with record, you need to declare them ahead of time in the span with something like status_code = tracing::field::Empty.
In reality you're meant to use span.enter() but you can't do this across awaits, so you have to use in_scope everywhere. This one isn't so bad though.

This altogether feels too hard for something that seems on the surface like it should be fairly simple. Is there a better approach that doesn't suffer all the issues I mentioned?

You can use instrument for an equivalent of span.enter() that works across await points.

In my case I only want to log in the top level function, so that isn't a great fit. At any rate, the need to use in_scope to deal with the awaits is only a minor inconvenience, vs the issues with nesting, dynamic fields, etc.
